# scroll viewer not working for canvas in windows phone 8

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, scrollview

I have a xaml file in which I declared `scroll viewer` with 15 `canvas`.

After executing the app, I can see only 10 canvas( 9 and half), When I scroll there, I can see the movement of all 9 and half canvas but no more canvas appears in the screen.
After the 10th canvas(9.5), I see only black background

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Height="607" Width="456">

<Canvas x:Name="canvas1" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub1" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 001" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date1" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author1" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas2" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub2" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 002" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date2" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author2" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas3" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub3" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 003" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date3" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author3" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas4" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub4" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 004" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date4" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author4" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas5" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub5" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 005" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date5" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author5" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas6" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub6" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 006" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date6" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author6" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas7" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub7" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 007" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date7" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author7" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas8" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub8" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 008" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date8" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author8" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas9" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub9" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 009" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date9" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author9" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas10" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub10" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 0010" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date10" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author10" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas11" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub11" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 0011" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date11" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author11" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas12" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub12" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 0012" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date12" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author12" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas13" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub13" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 0013" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date13" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author13" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas14" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub14" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 0014" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date14" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author14" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas15" Height="65" Background="Black" Margin="-13,0,-14,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="sub15" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 0015" Width="309" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="date15" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013" Width="99" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="author15" Canvas.Left="64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" Canvas.Top="45" Width="173" FontSize="13.333"/>
</Canvas>
```

[image: canvas on scroll viewer]

**EDIT**
If I make the scroll viewer shorter in height, It becomes scrollable but scrolls only upto 9 and half canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres your problem. StackPanel has a height of 607 so just remove that

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Height="607" Width="456">
```

Its not good practice to set the width like this due to different size devices try and use Grid with flexible layouts. For your example something like this. Note VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignments which are very useful in mapping out layouts.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">           
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="65" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="65" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid x:Name="panel1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="sub1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 001" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="author1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" FontSize="13.333"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="date1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013"  FontSize="16"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid x:Name="panel2" Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="sub2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Heading 002" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="author2"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="By-Gaurav Sharma" FontSize="13.333"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="date2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="02-Jul-2013"  FontSize="16"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>             
    </ScrollViewer> ... ...
```

Hope that helps